# Gulp 4 - Проблемы с watch и browsersync

Tags: gulp, browsersync, gulp-watch, gulp4

Обновил Gulp до версии 4.0.0 и столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Есть gulpfile.js, и при запуске таска watch browsersync постоянно обрабатывает файлы js без редактирования кода в файлах и в консоль каждую секунду выводятся сообщения о том что файлы js были изменены, и страница постоянно обновляется. Но данная проблема наблюдается только когда в таске Watch в ф-ции gulp.parallel() находится таск 'js', при его удалении все работает нормально. Порядок тасков такой же как в моем файле. Спасибо.

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
return gulp.src([
    'app/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js',
    'app/js/main.js' // always in the end
    ])
.pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'))
.pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})); });

gulp.task('sass', function() {
return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass')
.pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expand'}).on("error", notify.onError()))
.pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', prefix : ''}))
.pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions']))
.pipe(cleanCSS())
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
.pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})); });

gulp.task('watch', function(cb) {
gulp.parallel(
    'sass', 
    'js', 
    'browser-sync'
)(cb);

gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass', gulp.series('sass'));
gulp.watch(['app/js/**/*.js', 'app/js/main.js'], gulp.series('js'));
gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload); });
```

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Можно узнать, смогли вы её решить или нет? Очень интересно. Т.к Ваш пост единственный с такой проблемой.

Comment: @GeorgiiFilipov https://github.com/unsxxndxrk/Gulp-Starter-Pack

Comment: Watch смотрит туда же куда и компилятся файлы, нет?